# Fluent nhibernate: problem in where clause

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using fluent nhibernate.

I have written a piece of code like,

```
var data = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(CustomerNameValueList))
                        .Add(Expression.Eq("CustomerId","3"))
                        .List<CustomerNameValueList>();
```

but the query generated by nhibernate is looks like

```
select column1,column2,column3 from table where CustomerId=?
```

problem is with "customerId=?"
expeted : CustomerId=3"

why customerId=? rather than customerId=3

please help me.

Comment: You are asking for help but you didn't ask a question. What's wrong with this query? What are the results you are expecting?

Comment: problem is with "customerId=?" expeted : CustomerId=3"

why customerId=? rather than customerId=3

Comment: Where did you get that query from? Is it actually being executed against the database?

Comment: yes, it is actually being executed against the database

Comment: Are you *sure* that is exactly what is being executed by the SQL database? In my experience NHibernate will show the queries with ? where parameters will be placed but will replace them with the actual values before sending the query to the DB. If it *is* being executed, presumably it would result in an error message; could you post that?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with this query. The '?' in the log will be substituted with the string value of "3". If your column type is actually an int you may have a problem here. The parameterization of the query is what you want to protect you against SQL injection attacks. If the generated query had CustomerId='3' as you were expect and the '3' came from a textbox on a web page, then it would be possible to inject more SQL such as '3' DELETE FROM MyUserTable.